# What is the expected value of $x/(a+x)$ where $x$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and $a > 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, expected-value, poisson-distribution

I am trying to compute the following expectation, where $x$ follows a Poisson distribution, i.e.,:
$$
\mathbb{E}[x] = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x+a} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!},
$$
where $\lambda > 0$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a > 0$.

I.e., I am wondering whether there is a closed-form expression for this summation.
It clearly converges, since the fraction introduced in each term of the sum (weighted by the probability) is less than or equal to the value $x$ itself.  However, I can't figure out how to reduce it.  There are a lot of examples when $a$ is an integer, in which the denominator $x+a$ can be combined with the factorial in the denominator of the Poisson probability, but since $a$ may not be an integer, I don't see how it could be combined.

Similarly, I'm also trying to determine the following expectation as well:

$$
\mathbb{E}[x] = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{a}{x+a} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!},
$$
which has almost the same form. The $a$ in the numerator can be remove from the summation in the latter expectation, whereas the $x$ in the numerator in the former can be combined with the factorial, so I imagine if a solution exists for one the same sort of approach would allow a solution for the other.

I know that for deriving mean and such, usually the approach is to reduce the infinite sum to just include $\lambda^x / x!$ so it can be replaced by $e^\lambda$, but I can't see how to do it here.

Comment: I believe you made a typo somewhere in the question. The summations don't use the index variable ($i$) anywhere.

Comment: The two sums add to $1$, so if you can determine one then you can definitely determine the other.

Comment: The second one is $ae^{-\lambda}\int_0^1 t^{a-1}e^{\lambda t}\,dt$ (elementary if $a$ is integer, otherwise not).

Comment: Thanks @metamorphy - can this integral be expressed with Gamma functions (or something else)?  It looks like it could be with an incomplete gamma function except for the fact that the exponent on $e$ is positive and not negative

Comment: Yes (close to @DrZafarAhmedDSc's answer), it is [IGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Holomorphic_extension) extended. BTW, the formula $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+1)(-\lambda)^n}{\Gamma(n+a+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\lambda)^n}{(a+1)\cdots(a+n)}$$ for the answer can be obtained from the integral by substituting $t=1-x$ and expanding $e^{-\lambda x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normalized Poisson distribtion is
$$f(k)=\frac{t^k}{k!} e^{-t}, t>0$$ Then the expectation value of $1/(k+a)$ is given by
$$E(1/(k+a))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+a} \frac{t^k}{k!} e^{-t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} u^{k+a-1}\frac{t^k}{k!} e^{-t}  du=e^{-t}\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(tu)^k}{k!} u^{a-1} du$$ $$\implies E(1/(k+a))= e^{-t} \int_{0}^{1} e^{tu} u^{a-1} du=e^{-t}[ (-t)^{-a}~ [\Gamma(a)-\Gamma(a,-t)]$$
Next 
$$E(a/(k+a))= ae^{-t} (-t)^{-a}~ [\Gamma(a)-\Gamma(a,-t)]$$
And
$$E(k/(k+a))=1- ae^{-t} (-t)^{-a}~[\Gamma(a)-\Gamma(a,-t)]$$
Finally, $$ (-t)^{-a}[\Gamma(a)-\Gamma(a,-t)] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!(k+a)},$$
which is all real for $t>0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but I think there is an error at the last step.  It makes sense for me up to this point:
$e^{-t} \int_{0}^{1} e^{tu} u^{a-1} du$
However, the next line does not seem to follow (maybe it's a typo) - how do you get the next line? That is the key part that needs fixing.  In particular, $(-t)^{-a}$ yields an imaginary number for non integer $a$ (as $t > 0$).  Further evaluating $\Gamma(a,-t)$ fails for $a>0$ and $t>0$ as in this problem (I get NaN when testing in stats packages).

Comment: @Brian Sorry one [ was misplaced in all three expression. I have edited it now. Thanks

Comment: @Brian Sorry my [ was again misplaced. Now ypu may please see my edit to check the reality of all expectation values.